# How can i read from excel file

Tags: c#, excel, list, file-io, dataset

Please can you help me with my actually script. I have done select from excel file but now i dont know how can i added value to my lists. I get data from more files together not only from one.

**Here is my actually scripts:**

Base button initiate event for read.

```
private void next_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < UniqueValue.traceToFile.Count; i++)
    {
        ReadFromExcel read = new ReadFromExcel();
        read.ReadData(UniqueValue.traceToFile[i]);
    }
}
```

**After next step is this:**

```
class ReadFromExcel : Config
{
    public void ReadData(string fullpath)
    {
        DataSet da = new DataSet();
        OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        string cell = "C7";
        string name = "List1";

        string FileName = fullpath;
        string _ConnectionString = string.Empty;
        string _Extension = Path.GetExtension(FileName);
        // Checking for the extentions, if XLS connect using Jet OleDB
        if (_Extension.Equals(".xls", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            _ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", FileName);
        }
        // Use ACE OleDb
        else if (_Extension.Equals(".xlsx", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            _ConnectionString = string.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=Excel 8.0", FileName);
        }

        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(_ConnectionString);
        string strCmd = "SELECT * FROM [" + name + "$" + cell + "]";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(strCmd, con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            da.Clear();
            adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
            adapter.Fill(da);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }

        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now I need that this result to be written to my list. i reading only one cells from every files.

**List for result is**

```
public static List<int> money = new List<int>();
```

I really thanks for all answers which can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below code will help you.
In this example dt, dt2 and dt3 will consider return from your function ReadData function which have datatable from excel.

```
public static List<int> money = new List<int>();

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt.Rows.Add();
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["ID"] = 1;
    dt.Rows[dt.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = "Test1";



    DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
    dt2.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt2.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt2.Rows.Add();
    dt2.Rows[dt2.Rows.Count - 1]["ID"] = 2;
    dt2.Rows[dt2.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = "Test2";


    DataTable dt3 = new DataTable();
    dt3.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(Int32));
    dt3.Columns.Add("Name");
    dt3.Rows.Add();
    dt3.Rows[dt3.Rows.Count - 1]["ID"] = 3;
    dt3.Rows[dt3.Rows.Count - 1]["Name"] = "Test2";


    money = (from row in dt.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])).ToList();
    money.AddRange((from row in dt2.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])).ToList());
    money.AddRange((from row in dt3.AsEnumerable() select Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"])).ToList());
}
```

Comment: i will try it. If it will be work for me so i write you.

Comment: Your idea is work but It's not exactly what I'm looking. For example i have 9 excel files. Every file contains any table with data. I will read only one cell from each files. Cell will be still same "C7" in all files. And i need value from C7 add to money list from all files. And please can you preserve my prevent for xls or xlsx file.

Comment: Ok so no problem execute sql query with your requirement.
Example every excel file have C7 column heading so execute query like 
string strCmd = "SELECT C7 FROM [" + name + "$" + cell + "]";
so your datatable have single column which you required.
And please describe your problem regarding xls or xlsx.

Answer (score -1):

```
Excel.Application excel;
Excel.Workbook wb;
Excel.Worksheet sh;

DataTable dt=new DataTable();

excel = new Excel.Application();
excel.Visible = true;
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("File Path");
sh = wb.Sheets.Add();
sh.Name = "Data";
count = 2;
sh.Cells[count, "A"].Value2 = "Column Name 1";
sh.Cells[count, "B"].Value2 = "Column Name 2";
sh.Cells[count, "C"].Value2 = "Column Name 3";
sh.Cells[count, "D"].Value2 = "Column Name 4";
sh.Cells[count, "E"].Value2 = "Column Name 5";
sh.Range["A" + count + "", "E" + count + ""].Font.Size = 12;
sh.Range["A" + count + "", "E" + count + ""].Borders.Color = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToOle(System.Drawing.Color.Black);
sh.Range["I2"].WrapText = true;

try
{
    con.Open();
    da.Clear();
    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    adapter.Fill(dt);
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
    sh.Cells[count, "A"].Value2 = row["Column Name"].ToString();
    sh.Cells[count, "B"].Value2 = row["Column Name"].ToString();
    sh.Cells[count, "C"].Value2 = row["Column Name"].ToString();
    sh.Cells[count, "D"].Value2 = row["Column Name"].ToString();
    sh.Cells[count, "E"].Value2 = row["Column Name"].ToString();
    }
    wb.SaveAs("File Path" + "File Nmae" + ".xls");
    excel.Workbooks.Close();
    excel.Quit();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}

finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

Comment: -1: you don't explain your code and your code only works if Excel is actually installed on the machine, and then wouldn't work if using ASP.NET.